# Extending the User model in django

Tags: django, django-models

http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/21/extending-the-django-user-model-with-inheritance/

When it comes to extending the User model, the above article list two methods: the old way (ForeignKey) and the new way (User model with inheritance). But at the same time, this article dates back to Aug 2008.

I am using Django's development version.

Would you recommend Extending the Django User model with inheritance or by using ForeignKey?

I read in a couple of posts that extending django.contrib.auth.models.User is not recommended, so I will not be looking at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the cleaner approach - if this can fit in your project architecture - is to have a distinct user profile model, and use the AUTH_PROFILE_MODEL setting to link it up to the Django User model.

See the [Django Doc about storing additional information for Users](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#auth-profiles)

Answer (score 1):

Dominique Guardiola is right. Use the AUTH_PROFILE_MODEL. James Bennett reiterated this in his 'Django in Depth' talk. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t_ziKY1ayCo&feature=related around 1hr:37mins.

- Decide on the application where we want to house our user's profile, let's call it BngGangOfFour.
- Define a Model class, lets name it UserProfile for clarity, and give it the extra field(s) we desire.

### BngGangOfFour/models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User) #notice it must contain a 1 to 1 field with the auth user.
    last_ip_address = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="")
```

- Edit settings.py to designate our newly created model as the user profile.

### settings.py

```
....
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'BngGangOfFour.UserProfile' #not case sensitive.
....
```

- Access the profile directly off the user objects.

### BngGangOfFour/views.py

```
....
def index(request):
    if request.user.get_profile().last_ip_address = "127.0.0.1":
        print("why hello me!")    
    return render_to_response('index.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

- Sip a cold beer and call it a day.

Answer (score 0):

The only time you can cleanly get away with extending `User` via inheritance is if you're writing an auth backend which will return an instance of the appropriate model instead.

Comment: The article describes how to write an auth backend to return an instance of the user. I am just posting the question to get a better feel of which would be better. I do have a preconception that "new way" = better